# Short format of large numbers with Humanizer

Tags: c#, .net, humanizer

I am using humanizr.net in a .NET project to format dates and it works really well.

Now I want to format large numbers to short - readable ones like this:
1234 -> 1.2K
50,323 -> 50.3K
Just like Facebook like counts...

Is there a way to do that using Humanizer?

Comment: Have you tried `.ToMetric()` ?

Comment: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#metric-numerals looks fairly close (essentailly a repeate of @Peter B's answer

Comment: I guess ToMetric will work as long as we are under 1 mio and using integers... however would like a specific solution if any!?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public static string FormatLargerNumbers(double number)
{
    string[] prefix = { string.Empty, "K", "M" };

    var absnum = Math.Abs(number);

    int add;
    if (absnum < 1)
    {
        add = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(absnum)) / 3);
    }
    else
    {
        add = (int)(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(absnum)) / 3);
    }

    var shortNumber = number / Math.Pow(10, add * 3);

    return string.Format("{0}{1}",shortNumber.ToString("0.#"), prefix[add]);
}

string formatted = FormatLargerNumbers(50323);
// Output : 50,3K
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a really great solution, lucky.

I needed this also, and have just modified your solution slightly so that I can also display in 'billions' as I was getting an *Out of Range* exception without it. Posting here in case anyone else needs for billions.

```
public static string FormatLargerNumbers(double number)
{
    string[] prefix = { string.Empty, "K", "M", "B" };

    var absnum = Math.Abs(number);

    double add;
    if (absnum < 1)
    {
        add = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(absnum)) / 3);
    }
    else
    {
        add = (int)(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(absnum)) / 3);
    }

    var shortNumber = number / Math.Pow(10, add * 3);

    return string.Format("{0}{1}", shortNumber.ToString("0.#"), 
    (prefix[Convert.ToInt32(add)]));
}
```